# Getting data from database and organize it 2 by 2

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

my problem looks like this: I have 3 products A,B and C. They have different values and they are stored in a DB.

I have 6 columns like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 ...
```

Currently i display them by value asc. I want to display them by value asc and also grouped 2 by 2, in columns, like this:

```
1A 2A 3B 4B 5C 6C
7A 8A 9B ...
```

I don't know very well sql so i don't know really how to order them to echo like this. Also i thought to save them in arrays and display them like echo $data_A[$i].$data_A[$i+1]; but won't look right if the number of products is not equal.

I want to display them in php with html. I have a container with 600 width and each div has 100 width.

I want to display on every row first 2 products to be Math books, next 2 books of Physics and 2 books of English.

[image: s]

the green border shows how are they grouped by product type.
Thanks

Comment: The ants go marching 2 by 2, hurrah, hurrah.
The ants go marching 2 by 2, hurrah, hurrah.
The ants go marching 2 by 2,
The little one stopped to tie his shoe....

Comment: interesting point, but any answers ? :D

Comment: It's unclear to me what your db schema is, what your data is, and what your select statement is... we need more detail.

Comment: @thebjorn They are books : Math English Phisics and the table : id(int A_I) type(varchar) value(float), nothing out of the ordinary. I want to know if i can do this from sql or i need something else.

Comment: You can do most things from sql, so "yes".  (please edit your question to include enough information for us to help you if you need a more detailed answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would order the sql so all `A` products come before all `B` products, and then order by id:

```
select ... order by product, id
```

(asc is default).

Then I would populate the three "columns" as `div` elements and add a `float:left` to them (pseudo code  -- it's been a while since I did php..):

```
echo "<div id=A style='float:left'>";
while ($data[$i].product == 'A') {
    // add $data[$i] to the A-div
    echo "<div class='data-item product-a' style='float:left'>";
    echo $data[$i];
    echo "</div>";
    ++$i;
}
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id=C style='float:left'>";
while ($data[$i].product == 'B') {
    // add $data[$i] to the B-div here
    ++$i;
}
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id=C style='float:left'>";
while ($data[$i].product == 'C') {
    // add $data[$i] to the C-div here
    ++$i;
}
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: ok, i can understand that, but can you explain better how data si added to A-div ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more detail (php isn't my native language, so take the syntax with a pinch of salt..)

Comment: Ok, thanks i understand now what you were trying to say. But i don't know if i can organize the divs like that. For the moment they are outputting as i explained : 1 2 3 4 5 6 when reaches 7 moves to the next row. Your example si good and i will try to create divs to do this.